# Не работает последний if при проверки длины конечного результата

Tags: python

```py
    def phone_number(number):
    allowed_characters = '+()-1234567890'
    symvols = ['-', '(', ')']
    for num in range(len(number)):
        if number[num] not in allowed_characters:           # Check allowed char
            return 'Not correct'
    #########
    if number[0] == '8':                                       # replase 8 with +7
        number = '+7' + number[1::]
    elif number[0] == '+' and number[1] == '7':                # checking where the number starts.
        print(number)
    else:
        print(number)
    #######
    if number[0] != '+':                             # Check правильность +
        return 'Not correct'
    ########
    for char in number:      # Check () and del
        if char not in symvols:
            number = list(number)
            step = 0
            if number[2 + step] == '(':
                del number[2 + step]
                step -= 1
            if number[6 + step] == ')':
                del number[6 + step]
                step -= 1
            if number[10 + step] == '-':
                del number[10 + step]
                step -= 1
            if ((13 + step) < len(number)) and (number[13 + step] == '-'):
                del number[13 + step]
            elif number [8] == '-' or number[10] == '-':
                del number[8]
                del number[10]
            return ''.join(number)

        if len(number[1::]) != 11:               !!!!! Вот эта часть
            return 'Not correct'
        else:
            return number

print(phone_number(input('Введите номер:')))
```

Comment: `**` уберите и будет возможно работать

Comment: нет нет это я тут обозначила часть, которая не работает)))

Comment: Так что тогда у вас возвращает функция?

Comment: вы можете описать словами, что должна делать данная функция и привести несколько примеров ее работы - т.е. показать несколько входных номеров и результат, который должна вернуть функция для каждого из этих номеров?

Comment: @MaxU согласен с вами.

Comment: `number[1::]` это же срез с 1 элемента, который возвращает новый лист, может вам надо проверять его длину? `if len(number[1::]) != 11:`

Comment: Мне нужно проверить длину конечного результата (номера), после того как из него все лишнее удалилось.

Comment: `len` вам в помощь

Comment: Проблема в том, что проверки не происходит. При проходе с debug не вижу этого. Так что  len проблемы не исправит)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if number[1::] != 11:
```

У вас же в `number` строка, срез от строки - это тоже строка. При сравнении строки с числом на равенство результат всегда будет `False`, а на неравенство - `True`. Видимо, нужно сравнивать со строкой, а не с числом, хотя логику вашего кода сложно понять, но по крайней мере это сравнение уже не будет давать константный результат:

```
if number[1::] != '11':
```